# Importing Certificate and Chain (PFX file) with C#

Tags: c#-4.0, x509certificate2

From a PKCS #12 (PFX file) how I can identity the type of the certificates inside the collection to open the proper X509Store?

```
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import("mycert.pfx", "mypass", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
foreach(X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
{
    // client cert? intermediate CA? root CA?
}
```

Usually in my scenario the client cert has a private key and the root CA has cert.Subject == cert.Issuer. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is to build a [X509Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and follow each [ChainElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For each certificate in this chain look if it has private key. If it has it is end entity certificate (I have not tested it but the chain should be built hierarchically so either end entity will be first or last element of the chain).

Anything other should be a CA certificate. But to be safe I would look for KeyUsage `Certificate Signing` extension and BasicConstraints `Subject Type=CA`.